# Firebase Cloud Function getting all documents in large collection not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get all documents in a collection of over 50,000 documents, some of which as labelled as isPositive=false and some as isPositive=true. However, when I run this, I get "Function execution took 3627 ms, finished with status: 'connection error'". Here is the code:

```
exports.findActualLikes = (request, response) => {
  let charactersAlreadyIn = { a: 0, b: 0 };

  return (
    db
      .collection("likes")
      .where("isPositive", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then((data) => {
        return data.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.data().characterId);
          if (doc.data().characterId in charactersAlreadyIn) {
            charactersAlreadyIn[doc.data().characterId]++;
          } else {
            charactersAlreadyIn[doc.data().characterId] = 1;
          }
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return response.json(charactersAlreadyIn);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      })
  );
};
```

Strangely, adding a `.limit(100)` before the `.get()` makes it work just fine with only the first 100 documents.

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: Could you edit the question to share in more detail what you find in the logs for the entire duration of the execution, other than the one error message?

Comment: How do you tested the function?

Comment: @DougStevenson This is all that appears in the Firebase cloud function logs.

Comment: @vitooh I just deploy the function and call it with an api get request

Comment: I reproduced it and was testing with `curl` and `gcloud` everything works without the error although quite long, so I wonder how do you get to this error.